# postgresql auth django (password authentication failed for user "BlogAdmin2")

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I followed the tutorial posted by Digital Ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-and-configure-a-new-django-project (How to set up django with postgres nginx and gunicorn on ubuntu)
I created a git hub private repo with the website and when I created the postgresql database with the folowing commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE PiaBlog;
CREATE USER BlogAdmin WITH PASSWORD 'Andrei1234';
ALTER ROLE BlogAdmin SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE BlogAdmin SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE BlogAdmin SET timezone TO 'UTC';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE PiaBlog TO BlogAdmin;
\q
```

and here is my django database config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'PiaBlog',
        'USER': 'BlogAdmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'Andrei1234,',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

When I run `python manage.py migrate` I get :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "BlogAdmin2"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "BlogAdmin2"
```

Does somebody know why do I get this problem I spent an hour searching for a typing error and I never found it.

Then I created a new user and I had this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "blog_admin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "blog_admin"
```

This is what I did:

```
CREATE DATABASE blogdb;
CREATE USER blog_admin WITH PASSWORD 'testing1234';
ALTER ROLE blog_admin SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE blog_admin SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE blog_admin SET timezone TO 'UTC';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE blogDB TO blog_admin;
\q

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'blogdb',
        'USER': 'blog_admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'testing123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the user you create is `BlogAdmin` and the user you are connecting with is `BlogAdmin2`?

Comment: Actually I created BlogAdmin and BlogAdmin2 with the same password for the same Data Base

Comment: Perhaps is that typo in  `'PASSWORD': 'Andrei1234,'`?

Comment: Downvote reason: This is an "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post." Please update to be free from typos.

Comment: The second case that was edited in has the same exact issue (typo) as the first case. Now user `blog_admin` is created with password `testing1234` and the `DATABASES` configuration uses `testing123`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this comma supposed to be in your password?

`'PASSWORD': 'Andrei1234,',`

Comment: Yes the comma is supposed to be there

Comment: You need to fix your question then: `CREATE USER BlogAdmin WITH PASSWORD 'Andrei1234';`. There is no comma in that password.